# Server USB hard drive not listed in /dev, but it appears in lsusb

Tags: usb, hard-drive, linux

I have a few servers that use 2TB Seagate GoFlex external drives for basic cPanel backups, but one of them is having trouble, and the drive is not listed as a device in /dev, even though it appears in lsusb.

Output of `lsusb`:

```
root@server-name [/sys/bus/usb/devices]# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bc2:50a5 Seagate RSS LLC FreeAgent GoFlex Desk USB 3.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04b4:6560 Cypress Semiconductor Corp. CY7C65640 USB-2.0 "TetraHub"
```

Output of `ls -lh /dev | grep sd`:

```
root@server-name [/sys/bus/usb/devices]# ls -lh /dev | grep sd
crw-rw----   1 root tty       2,  61 Mar  6 10:58 ptysd
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   0 Mar  6 10:58 sda
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   1 Mar  6 11:00 sda1
brw-rw----   1 root disk      8,   2 Mar  6 10:58 sda2
crw-rw----   1 root tty       3,  61 Mar  6 10:58 ttysd
```

I have tried to power cycle the USB port via the popular usbreset.c script, manually set power level to suspend/auto, set authorized to 0 (and back to 1), etc. However, none of this seems to do anything to get it recognized.

Output of `dmesg`:

```
[2439599.103034] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[2440600.692207] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device number 4 using ehci_hcd
[2440600.858527] usb 1-3: device firmware changed
[2440600.858547] usb 1-3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[2440600.961020] usb 1-3: new high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[2440601.128405] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bc2, idProduct=50a5
[2440601.128410] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[2440601.128414] usb 1-3: Product: GoFlex Desk
[2440601.128416] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Seagate
[2440601.128417] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: NA0M0LAZ
[2440601.128510] usb 1-3: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
[2440601.128844] scsi5 : SCSI emulation for USB Mass Storage devices
[2440601.129201] usb-storage: device found at 5
[2440601.129203] usb-storage: waiting for device to settle before scanning
[2440602.129185] usb-storage: device scan complete
[2440622.803210] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[2440643.797143] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[2440664.797199] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
[2440685.797139] usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
```

Finally, output of `lsblk`, in case that is helpful:

```
root@server-name [~/usbreset]# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0                         7:0    0   500M  0 loop /tmp
sda                           8:0    0 135.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1                        8:1    0   500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                        8:2    0   135G  0 part 
  ├─vg_angel-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm  /
  ├─vg_angel-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─vg_angel-lv_home (dm-2) 253:2    0  77.2G  0 lvm  /home
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Output of `cat /proc/scsi/scsi`:

```
root@server-name [~/usbreset]# cat /proc/scsi/scsi 
Attached devices:
Host: scsi0 Channel: 00 Id: 32 Lun: 00
  Vendor: DP       Model: BACKPLANE        Rev: 1.05
  Type:   Enclosure                        ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi0 Channel: 02 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: DELL     Model: PERC 6/i         Rev: 1.11
  Type:   Direct-Access                    ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
Host: scsi1 Channel: 00 Id: 00 Lun: 00
  Vendor: HL-DT-ST Model: CD-ROM GCR-8240N Rev: 1.10
  Type:   CD-ROM                           ANSI  SCSI revision: 05
```

Output of `cat /proc/usb-storage/5`

```
root@server-name [~/usbreset]# cat /proc/scsi/usb-storage/5 
   Host scsi5: usb-storage
       Vendor: Seagate
      Product: GoFlex Desk
Serial Number: NA0M0LAZ
     Protocol: Transparent SCSI
    Transport: Bulk
       Quirks:
```

Comment: What is the output of `/proc/scsi/scsi`?

Comment: @MatthewIfe Added. Thx!

Comment: Also added output of /proc/usb-storage/5, in case that helps.

Comment: If you have the following path, try this: `echo 1> /sys/class/scsi_device/5\:0\:0\:0/device/rescan`

Comment: I did not have the path you mentioned. However, I did run this, and it completed, but it didn't change anything that I could tell: `root@server-name [/sys/class/scsi_host/host5]# echo "- - -" > scan`

Comment: Does a `ls -laR /dev/disk/` list the device in any other (unexpected) way? Possibly a device not matching `sd*`? It would be unusual, but you never know.

Comment: echo "scsi add-single-device 5 0 0 0" > /proc/scsi/scsi. By the way, what was the output (in /var/log/messages and/or in dmesg) of the rescan on host5?

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie Tried that just now. Nothing changed, and the same dmesg output: `usb 1-3: reset high speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd`. I'm starting to think that this thing is just dead in the water.

Comment: What about restarting udev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same model of disk and the same model of motherboard (or USB card) on all the servers with identical drivers, and if all of them but one works, then the problem is likely a hardware problem.

The first piece of hardware I would try replacing was the cable, since that's the easiest piece to replace. If that does not help, I'd swap two of the disks between two of the servers to see if the problem follows the disk or stays on the same server.

Answer (score 0):

You have udev stopped would be my guess. Also see my comment on your question.